# The def code seems to be doing something to my code that i cant understand

Tags: function, python-3.x

My code worked fine before I added the 'def menu()' code and 'menu()' code in but now it doesnt seem to work! Any ideas on why not? I just get no return, just '>>>'! FYI: All indentations are correct as they were fine on similar code and worked fine before the 'def' function was introduced into the code.

```
def menu() :
     print("Please enter the number corresponding with the option you would like to pick.")
     print("1. Record Purchase(s)")
     print("2. Retrieve Previous Purchase(s)")
     option=input("> ")

 if option == "1":
      customer_id1=input("Customer ID: ")
      file=open(customer_id1.capitalize()+".txt","a")
      info=input("Please enter all purchases seperated by commas: ")
      file.write(info+"\n")
      file.close()
      print("PURCHASE RECORD SUCCESSFUL")
      import time
      time.sleep(5)
      menu()

 if option == "2":
      customer_id2=input("Customer ID: ")
      file=open(customer_id2+".txt","r")
      print(file.read())
      time.sleep(10)
      menu()

 else:
      print("Sorry, that doesnt seem to be an option, returning to menu.")
      menu()
```

Comment: First thing: Get your indentation straight.

Comment: It is straight on python itself, it messed up a bit when putting it onto here.

Comment: Yeah, but the code here is all people can see. Provide them with as error-free code as you can so they can concentrate on the relevant bits.

Comment: Ive now made it easier to see, Tomalak!

Comment: No, you've made it harder. A screenshot of code is completely useless. That's like going to the car repair shop bringing only a photo of your car. ;)

Comment: Very true I suppose but after 10 mins of trying, ive managed to get it to show up properly, would that make it easier!

Comment: Your code is still not indented properly. Python is indent-sensitive. How far you indent your code determines when it runs. In your code above, Python sees the `if` as part of your `menu` function body and I'm pretty sure you don't want that.

Comment: Yeh but even the first bit doesn't show up when I start the code, I just get '>>>'

Comment: If the above is your entire program then none of it will run because you never call `menu()` anywhere.

Comment: What is `option` set to before this code runs?